# Print message when in searching, the input of user doesnt match with the database value

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have this code and i need to print when it not finds the country or city a message like this

```
" if(!rs.next()){
           out.println("NOT FOUND <a href= \"Choises Code 1.jsp\">Try Again</a>" );"
```

the above code , prints me the message "not found .... " at both situations either find either not the country or city , i need to print the message only when not found the match...Alternatively to a  c code will be something like this : if ("select ...." ! = varialbe) printf( not found)  my main code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>destcode</title>
    </head>
    <style> Stable, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

    }
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
         <%

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
   Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
   Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
   String search=request.getParameter("search");
  ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEST WHERE COUNTRY='"+search+"'");     
  if(!rs.next()){
       out.println("NOT FOUND <a href= \"Choises Code 1.jsp\">Try Again</a>" );

  }
 while(rs.next()){ %>
   <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>City</th> 
    <th>Url of Destination</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("COUNTRY") %></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("CITY") %> </td> 
    <td> <a href=<%=rs.getString("URL") %> > <%=rs.getString("URL") %> </a>
        <% } %>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>




  <%  
   myStatement.close(); 
   myConnection.close(); %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: *"this code prints me when doesnt find the country or city the not found etc... but when it finds it also print it."*. It prints *you*? And when *it* finds *it*, *it* prints *it*? Could you clear this up please?

Comment: the above code , prints me the message "not found .... " at both situations either find either not the country or city , i need to print the message only when not found the match...Alternatively to a  c code will be something like this :  if ("select ...." = varialbe) printf( Success) else printf ( not found)

Comment: Oh I see. You may want to read over the how to ask guide which has a lot of really nice tips on details to include in your question, and formatting tips which will help make sure your question can be answered quickly and correctly!

Comment: Here's my generic "have a look at the guide comment" -> 
Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!